# SCCM 2007 Collection based on AD Group, not showing members?

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

I have a collection created based on a security group in AD. I added a machine to the security group but it is not showing as a member of the collection. Is there a discovery that needs to happen or do I need to add it as a resource as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run `Discovery Data Cycle` from the machine in question or `Update Collection Membership` in the console.